# Nodejs query for uploading photos

Tags: node.js

I am new to `nodejs`. I am basically using `express`, and I have to create a form to upload photos. So far I have created a file called `upload.handlebars` where I have written the following code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploads" method="post"> 
<input type="file", id = "image", name="image", accept="image/*"> 
<input type='submit' id='tags' value='Upload'>
```

I have another file called `router.js` where I have written the post function. One of the lines in the post function is:

```
fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {
```

However, I get an error as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined at Object.handle....
```

How should I specify the 'name' of the image file in my `router.js`?

Comment: What are those commas in the <input type=file...>?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have multiparty middleware enabled.

https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty

Latest express doesn't come with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use express to solve this problem quickly. to know more read the folowing page [express api reference](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html)

for now the following code may help you -

```
app.post('<your path>',express.bodyParser(),function(req,res){
    console.log(req.files);//to get all the files uplaoded
});
```

make sure express version should 3.4